# Interface que define a assinatura de forma genérica dos métodos a serem implementados

Tags: java, interface, genéricos

Eu possuo três classes:

1. RepositorioSolicitante
2. RepositorioMotorista
3. RepositorioViagem

Todas possuem os seguintes métodos com exceção do RepositorioViagem que não possui o "Alterar". O Objeto pode se referir as classes Motorista, Solicitante e Viagem.

1. Adicionar void
2. Remover void
3. Alterar boolean
4. Buscar Objeto
5. ExibirTodos void
6. BuscarTodos ArrayList

Gostaria de saber como implementar uma Interface única para os 3 Repositórios com os métodos acima de forma genérica, para poder utilizar qualquer classe que eu passar. Sejam adicionar com Solicitante, Motorista ou Viagem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar um tipo genérico na `interface` da seguinte forma:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public interface ICRUD<T> {
  void adicionar(T objeto);
  void remover(T objeto);
  boolean alterar(T objeto);
  T buscar(int id);
  void exibirTodos();
  ArrayList<T> buscarTodos();
}
```

E utilizá-lo, por exemplo, da seguinte forma:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CRUDRepositorioSolicitante implements ICRUD<RepositorioSolicitante>{...}
```

Caso queira obrigar os objetos a serem herdados de alguma classe (digamos que seja `Repositorio` você só precisa alterar a declaração da interface para:

```
public interface ICRUD<T extends Repositorio> {...}
```

**EDIT**

No caso da classe que não terá o método `alterar` você pode lançar a seguinte exceção:

```
throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Não suportado.");
```

Comment: Nossa, criou a classe com o mesmo nome que eu estava criando :p Só um detalhe, não precisa de `public` e vale adicionar que a classe `RepositorioViagem` vai ter que implementar tudo, independente se vai usar ou não o método `alterar`.

Comment: @diegofm fiquei com dúvida no alterar também, será que a melhor forma é criar `2 interfaces`?

Comment: Não, é só não implementar, deixar o método vazio, ou lançar uma `UnsupportedOperationException` dentro do método caso algum desavisado tente implementar

Comment: Ela ficaria vazia mesmo.

Comment: minha dúvida era mais quanto a forma que seria "digitada", creio que a falta do <T> no nome da interface bugava toda vez que eu usava o T nos métodos.

Comment: @diego é interessante colocar a parte do `public` e da exception na resposta?

Comment: @Sorack olha, a parte da exceção eu acho válida como sugestão, agora o modificador, eu nunca utilizei, mas fiquei na duvida se é dispensavel mesmo.

Comment: @diegofm o modificador pode ser `protected` por isso dá pra especificar

Comment: @sorack, pode não, todos os métodos da interface são obrigatóriamente publicos, por isso a IDE não reclama do public, mas tambem não reclama se não adicionar ele. protected da erro de sintaxe.

Comment: @diegofm verdade... então nem precisava especificar mesmo